# Creating a Dev Solution in Power Automate

Tags: power-automate

I have recently built a quite extensive flow that is now in use but requires further enhancements. Rather than making those enhancements in the working flow, is there a way to create an exact replica of the solution to use for development purposes? I have explored the clone a solution feature and it seems like that is better use for versioning as it locks the original and creates a copy that you can roll back to if needed. However we would like to have an exact copy to work in while the original flow is still in use and not locked.

I have also tried "Save As" from the flow within the solution but that takes a copy as a stand alone flow that cannot be loaded into a solution (from what I can see). Is this possible at all or does it need to be imported into a different account with a different license in order to work independently?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try export feature and upload it in your dev environment. you just need to re-establish the connection.

[image]